# как узнать длинну шаблонного массива?

Tags: c++, массивы, шаблоны-с++

Задание: сделать итератор по массиву(массив может быть любого типа).Соответственно я делаю класс и метод возращения элемента с массива шаблонным.Длину массива узнаю с помощью шаблонного метода strLen,но что-то идет не так и мне выдает мусор.

Пытался измерять длину с помощью sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]) и просто sizeof(array), но
выдает не все числа.Остановился на методе strLen

```
#ifndef ARRAYITERATOR_H
#define ARRAYITERATOR_H

template <class T>
class ArrayIterator {
private:
    int currentI;
    T* array;
public:
    ArrayIterator(T* arr) : array(arr), currentI(0){}

    void next() {
        if(over()) {
            return;
        }
        currentI += 1;
    }

    T strLen(T str[]) {
        int len = 0;
    
        for ( ; str[len] != '\0'; len++ );
            return len;
    }

    bool over() {
        int size = strLen(array);
        return array[currentI] == array[size];
    }

    void operator++() {
        next();
    }

    void operator++(int) {
        operator++();
    }

    T value() {
        return array[currentI];
    }

    int operator*() {
        return value();
    }
};

#endif //ARRAYITERATOR_H
```

main :

```
#include "ArrayIterator.cpp"

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int array[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
    ArrayIterator<int> seq5(array);

    for ( ; !seq5.over(); seq5++ ) {
         cout << seq5.value() << " ";
    }

    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

output in console :

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 4201104 3416064 4198752 4198752 3416064 4198752 6356816 4198619 1 16982720 16979808 4214788 6356804 -1 6356800 1974258880 1239290752 -2 6356804 1974258279
```

Comment: Вы ищите до двоичного нуля в строке, а никто не сказал, что в памяти после вашего массива окажется 0. Кроме того никто не мешает хранить 0 в самом массиве. Лично я не знаю способа узнать размер массива, кроме как передать его явно снаружи. Но это не значит что его нет

Comment: Если вы планируете передавать именно вот такой готовый массив — то используйте шаблон с количеством элементов `template <class T, size_t N> class ArrayIterator {...` `ArrayIterator(T (&arr)[N]) : array(arr), currentI(0){}`

Answer (score 1):

Можно — если будете конструировать класс именно из массива — примерно так:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

template <class T, size_t N>
class ArrayIterator {
private:
    int currentI;
    T* array;
public:
    ArrayIterator(T (&arr)[N]) : array(arr), currentI(0){}

    void next() {
        if(over()) {
            return;
        }
        currentI += 1;
    }

    bool over() {
        return currentI == N;
    }

    void operator++() {
        next();
    }

    void operator++(int) {
        operator++();
    }

    T value() {
        return array[currentI];
    }

    int operator*() {
        return value();
    }
};

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int array[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
    ArrayIterator seq5(array);

    for ( ; !seq5.over(); seq5++ ) {
         cout << seq5.value() << " ";
    }

    cout << endl;

}
```

А можно так:

```
template <class T>
class ArrayIterator {
private:
    int currentI;
    size_t N;
    T* array;
public:
    ArrayIterator(T* arr, size_t N) : N(N), array(arr), currentI(0){}

    ....  // Все как и ранее

    int array[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
    ArrayIterator seq5(array,size(array));

    ....  // Все как и ранее
```